# how to mask input IP Address in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, input-mask

I need IP Address mask input because ip address can be `999.99.999.99` or `99.9.99.9` 
`react-input-mask` doesn't support different length.What do you suggest?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this example using `react-input-mask`: https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask/issues/104